# Reverse the order of 8 poisonous substances

Tags: mathematics, strategy, mechanical-puzzles

8 very poisonous substances named s1 to s8 are kept in a safety room.
The substances are kept in ascending order (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7 and s8).
In the room there are 3 robots.

First robot can "rotate left" the order of the substances.
If the order is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) the robot will make it (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,a)

Second robot can split the substances into 2 parts then reverse the order of each part.
If the order is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) the robot will make it (d,c,b,a,h,g,f,e)
But the robot is a bit broken, so the resulting order is a bit wrong.
The resulting order will become (d,c,a,b,h,g,f,e).

Third robot can split the substances into 4 parts then reverse the order of each part
If the order is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) the robot will make it (b,a,d,c,f,e,h,g)

**Questions**

How many minimum steps needed by using the robots to reverse the order into descending order :

1. If the second robot is not broken.
2. After the second robot is broken.

Show the steps !

Comment: You could have just named them the numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) you know...

Comment: Do you know of any way of proving that the minimum solution ***is*** the minimum other than brute-force search? If you do, you should post it as an answer — you might earn some more rep!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question 1 is already answered by others.

The answer to Question 2 is

> 14 steps

By doing

> 2 dcabhgfe
> 1 cabhgfed
> 3 achbfgde
> 1 chbfgdea
> 2 fbchaedg
> 2 hcfbgdea
> 1 cfbgdeah
> 1 fbgdeahc
> 2 dgfbchae
> 2 bfdgeahc
> 1 fdgeahcb
> 3 dfeghabc
> 1 feghabcd
> 2 hgfedcba

I'm pretty sure it's the least number of steps because I used a computer program to find it but I don't have a proof

Comment: There should be a way algebraically speaking to see if certain steps cancel each other out.

Answer (score 5):

It's

> 5 if the 2nd robot isn't broken.

> (s1, s3, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8) 
> 2nd Robot    
> (s4, s3, s2, s1, s8, s7, s6, s5)    
> 1st Robot x 4    
> (s8, s7, s6, s5, s4, s3, s2, s1)

Not sure for second

Comment: Right, it's easy for 1st question. The second question is much harder.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya yes it is!

Comment: first × 8 just lands you back at the original order.

Answer (score 5):

For unbroken robot,

> 5 steps is the best case; Beastly Gerbil already identified the solution:
>  second robot × 1, first robot × 4.

For broken robot,

> the optimal solution is:  **21312211221312**.
>  I believe this matches what Ivo Beckers posted, and there are no better  solutions.
>
>  - first robot rotating the sequence can't reverse the order.
>  - third robot exchanging pairs can't reverse the order, because two in a row just puts you back where you were; putting a rotation in the middle doesn't get it reversed; and after enough (4) repetitions of robot 3 + robot 1 you end up back where you started.
>  - second robot lets you order the first half in reverse, but not the second; cycling 4x to try to fix that will end up messing up the first half, leaving you (eventually) in the same place you'd be after one use of robot 3.
>  - **however**, other uses of robot 2 with other than 4 cycles can provide a solution.

In the interest of completeness,

> an exhaustive search by a non-bugged computer determined there are 5 solutions of 16 moves, 1 solution of 14 moves, and nothing lower.

Comment: There is only 1 solution for 14 moves, but There are more than 30 solutions for 16 moves.